# Equivalence relations among algebraic cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, intersection-theory

In the book *3264 and All That* by Eisenbud & Harris, the authors claim that for smooth projective varieties admitting an affine stratification, the algebraic equivalence relation and the rational equivalence relation define the same intersection theory (p. 553). Anyway, they do not give an explicit reference where one can find the proof of this claim. I am looking for such a reference.

Comment: In fact more is true: the cycle class map $CH^{*}(X)\rightarrow H^{*}(X)$ is an isomorphism. See e.g. Fulton's *Intersection theory*, Examples 1.9.1 and 19.1.11 (b).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: @abx: You might consider posting your above comment as an answer so that the question counts as being answered in the system.

Comment: @J W: OK, just done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact more is true: the cycle class map $CH^*(X)\rightarrow H^*(X)$
is an isomorphism. See e.g. Fulton's Intersection theory, Examples 1.9.1 and 19.1.11 (b).